# Redirect all website pages to wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

In my project, I'm using wordpress as a headless cms for just the wp rest apis and with a blank theme ( just the index.php and style.css). I want the user to redirect to the wordpress dashboard when he visits the homepage in frontend. I tried putting the redirect in the index.php in the root directory in wordpres like this

```
header("Location: /wp-admin");

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';
```

But its not working and I'm not sure if its right too. How can I do this?

Comment: do an `exit` after changing the header location

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir If I do that I get an error when saving a post in the dashboard. I'm pretty sure that's not the right place to put the redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by simply adding this in the index.php file inside the theme

```
header("Location: ".admin_url());
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try on your functions.php something like this:

```
<?php

function redirect_wpadmin(){
    $url2go = get_bloginfo('url').'/wp-admin';
    if (is_home()) {
        wp_redirect($url2go);
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('init','redirect_wpadmin');
```

This should do the work c:

--Update--
I also think that you can do this with htaccess, adding inside and at the bottom of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`:

```
Redirect 301 / /wp-admin
```

Comment: It seems wrong to run a strpos() and if for every page load when I dont have a single page in the frontend website and just want it to run on index page

Comment: Nice. I liked the htaccess redirect. Unfortunately I use nginx so I can't use this